# Changing ~280 controls from visible=true to visible=false takes about 8-9 seconds (too long)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am wondering if there is something I can do to speed this up, I have narrowed the time lag to this section of code below. I am wondering if there is something else I can do to make this at least 2-3 times faster.

```
form1.SuspendLayout();
foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, bool> i in ItemControlUpdates)
{
    i.Key.Visible = i.Value;
}
form1.ResumeLayout();
```

Edit:
Thank you guys for the comments, I corrected my code and hope it indicates my specific problem. (I do not need to write to file)

Edit2:
The 280 controls are user controls and it is a requirement for my application to view all of them or some of them when the sorting selections are made.

Edit3: 
Answer is: SuspendLayout() must be called on the parent to be effective, I incorrectly used it on the form when I needed to use it on the panel that the controls were within.

Comment: You are opening file writing to it and then closing it 280times. Did you try to switch visibility without writing to log?

Comment: Sorry I have not an answer, but a question: 280 controls? Are you joking?

Comment: as @szpic suggested, try that. also just a though, you could use multithreading

Comment: @amyn: Multithreading is not a good idea, because UI controls must only ever be manipulated on the thread that created them (usually "the UI thread") so by introducing multiple threads, you'd also introduce the need to switch contexts.

Comment: This was my first time posting a question here, and I had copy paste problems and then miss-typed something. It is corrected and I hope to get some more input.

Comment: What is `ItemControlUpdates`?

Comment: @IVAAAN123 ItemControlUpdates is a List<KeyValuePair<Control, bool>> that contains references to the Controls of interest and whether I want them visible or not.

Comment: @Steven I didn't try but: you suspend layout on form...are all controls its children? If there are nested containers they won't be affected by SuspendLayout(). Moreover it'll force multiple refreshes (with tons of controls to redraw), is it possible to hide form itself (or at least a top container for all your controls)?

Comment: @Steven It takes 0.08s to set visible of 300 controls for me. Maybe `ItemControlUpdates` is property and it contains additional computations?

Comment: @Adriano The controls are nested inside a panel so I bet you have a point. What do you mean by "hide" the top container? I think that may be where my solution lies.

Comment: It still strikes me that having 280 controls implies a design error somewhere. If the objective is to show 280 different graphic objects of some kind on the screen, then don't these graphic objects have some interrelation, so it would make sense that these graphic objects be grouped so that one user control is responsible for showing all of the related graphic objects? So then maybe instead of having 280 user controls you have 20 or 50 or some more reasonable number?

Comment: Are there any controls with asigned EventHandlers on VisibilityChanged, LostFocus, etc.?

Comment: The solution to my problem can be found below posted by me. stakx's answer is also very informative to check out. It won't allow me to select an answer for 2 days so we shall see if I remember to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that the controls were embedded in a panel and exchanging form1.SuspendLayout() with panel.SuspendLayout() made this action take no time at all. A couple people hinted at this and I recommend people check out stakx answer as it includes other/similar possible solutions to a problem similar to this one.

Here is the fixed code that works great:

```
                cPanel.SuspendLayout();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<Control, bool> i in ItemControlUpdates)
                {
                    i.Key.Visible = i.Value;
                }
                cPanel.ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: So much for 'facts about winforms'. Don't try with 8k+ controls though..!

Comment: @TaW: You're right, even facts are relative. :) But seriously: With Windows Forms, you usually *are* better off with simpler forms. For example, build a form with 300 controls and things work fine, once you've added tricks like `SuspendLayout` and the like. Then you add data binding, your form becomes incredibly sluggish again, so you add even more tricks and hacks, and you end up with really horrible code. (Unfortunately I am speaking out of experience.) That's why I suggested re-designing the whole form into something less complex.

Comment: You are right, of course. Let the Usercontrol be a little more complex and you may well run into problems. As usual, one needs to know the limits of each technology..

Answer (score 3):

[The fact is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120723/changing-280-controls-from-visible-true-to-visible-false-takes-about-8-9-second/27121420#comment42748730_27121745) (as was stated in [this comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120723/changing-280-controls-from-visible-true-to-visible-false-takes-about-10-seconds/27120904#comment42742536_27120723)) that manipulating so many (280) controls is bound to be slow, simply because Windows Forms is not super-fast. Since you haven't said more about the structure and layout of your form(s) I can only give you a couple generic recommendations:

- If some of the controls that you are manipulating are not actually embedded in `form1`, then `form1.SuspendLayout()` will have no effect for these controls. Suspend the layouting of all relevant forms.
- You could try grouping some controls that logically belong together into a single user control, or at least into a `Panel`; you'd then only make that container control visible or invisible. Especially when you are using layout features such as `AutoSize`, that might mean that Windows Forms has to do less layout computations.
- Reduce the total number of controls on your form drastically. Chances are that with so many controls on it, your form is too complex from a user experience (UX) point of view: You are asking too much from the user at one time, and your form might just end up being confusing or even unusable. Consider redesigning the form. If the workflow really is that complicated, you might at least split it up into a series of simpler steps – think wizard / multi-step dialog.

Comment: @Steven what they're pointing out is that apart from the first two suggestions there is very little you can do about the speed.  So you need to go back to the beginning and rethink the approach.  Maybe some kind of Wizard interface, one form leads to another etc, pop-up sub forms might also work.  If your insistent on sticking with the layout you have then you're gonna need a progress bar or some way of indicating that the operation is going to take an age.

Comment: @stakx The first bullet was really the closest to my answer, but I didn't realize it because you said suspend all relevant forms when my solution was to suspend the Parent Control of my 280 controls. Thank you so much, again, for your help!